# Why is my website slow to load images from just using <img>? is there an better way to insert photos without slowing my website the more I insert?

Tags: javascript, html, css, database, mongodb

I am having a situation where when the more I add photos to a website for blogging, the slower my website becomes. It even becomes slower when running on mobile devices. Below is the code I writing:

```
    <img src="images/photos/2022_09_05/2.jpg" alt="" title="Drive to airport">
    <img src="images/photos/2022_09_05/3.jpg" alt="" title="Getting ready for takeoff">
    <img src="images/photos/2022_09_05/4.jpg" alt="" title="Exit of USA">
    <img src="images/photos/2022_09_05/5.jpg" alt="" title="Leaving LAX">
    <img src="images/photos/2022_09_05/6.jpg" alt="" title="Goodbye California">
    <img src="images/photos/2022_09_05/7.jpg" alt="" title="Views">
    <img src="images/photos/2022_09_05/8.jpg" alt="" title="More views">
```

Is there another way to go about this,
such as using databases and using software such as MongoDB for faster implementations? I am not
very familiar with databases and
would like to ask for some recommendations. I would like to know if MongoDB is an option.

Comment: If the images are large, consider loading them only when the user is close to scrolling them into view. Also make sure their displayed size is similar to their resolution - don't show a 2000x2000 image in a 300x300 frame

Comment: Can using databases give me faster response times to loading images or is it irrelevant?

Comment: No, they'll be worse than a static image already on your server's filesystem. Databases generally aren't meant for large blob-like data like images anyway.

Comment: This is a stupid question in my regards but for example, how does Instagram manage to load billions of images fast without losing quality? Any advice you can give me?

Comment: By using the approach in my first comment, and also by having a (well, many) servers with great upload speeds

Comment: can you give me an example to use as a reference moving forward? Would really appreciate it. also, the images are right next to each other. An entire page just of images to be exact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to see improvements by decreasing the amount of bandwidth required for the initial page load, and by downloading only the data that's necessary, and only when it's necessary.

- Don't load the images until they're near the viewport. Add the [`loading="lazy"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading) attribute to your images. (for older browsers, you'll need [a polyfill](https://github.com/mfranzke/loading-attribute-polyfill) or another approach)
- Only load as much image data as you need. Look at how large the images appear on your page, and compare them to the size of the images when opened in a standalone tab or image viewer. To save on bandwidth, the sizes shouldn't be that different. If the size of the image on the page is small, for example, the `src` it links to should also be small - otherwise you'll be sending a lot of extra data for no visible effect.
- If you still experience sluggishness with the above, you could also upgrade your server to one with better upload speed, ideally one in a similar geographical area as your viewers.

Putting the images into a database won't help at all because then you'll have to retrieve them from the database each time. Having a bunch of static image files is just fine.

Comment: thank you for this really do appreciate receiving feedback from someone smart as yourself!! any other recommendations moving forward? I am going to be adding a lot of data and want to know what approach would best fit my need to make the website as sufficient to viewers as possible

Comment: You could check that nothing else on the page is requiring too much bandwidth or processing power, at least until the browser is idle (or close to idle). For example, don't import a huge JS library unless it's actually going to be used, and you might do so only after the essentials to display and interact with the site are loaded.